# How to display a list in a create view in React-admin

Tags: react-admin

I include a ContactList into Create Simple Form with React-Admin. The list is loaded, but when I sort, navigate or change filter, I'm redirecting to my ContactList page (/#/contacts). It's NOT a Many to many reference so I can't use component ReferenceManyField.

I've tried to change the basePath for my ContactList

```
<Create {...props}>
   <SimpleForm>
       <TextInput source="name"/>
        <ContactList {...props}
                     basePath="/marketing/create"
                     className="FormInput-input-100"
                     resource="contacts"
                     match={isExact : true, params: {}, path: "/contacs/", url: "/contacts/"}
                     location={hash: "", pathname: "/contacts"};
                     hasList={true}
                     hasCreate={false}
                     hasEdit={false}
                     hasShow={false}
        />
   </SimpleForm>
</Create>
```

Comment: Ok I find. Just remove props match and location and it's works ```<ContactList {...props}
                     basePath="/marketing/create"
                     className="FormInput-input-100"
                     resource="contacts"
                     hasList={true}
                     hasCreate={false}
                     hasEdit={false}
                     hasShow={false}
        />```